# Google plus api nuget package download

Tags: google-plus, nuget, nuget-package

I want to include Plus.v1 namespace in my mvc application. I am unable to find any package on nuget to download the dll's.

Comment: I think Install-Package Google.Apis.Plus.v1 is the nuget package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console: Install-Package Google.Apis.Plus.v1

To access PMC (Package Manager Console) go to "Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console"

Answer (score 1):

www.nuget.org has been experiencing some problems, especially related to search. Please check back later and sorry for the inconveniences.